# Post data using javascript on same origin/domain (Security Risks?

Tags: javascript, http, security, ssl

Is there any Security risks to send Post data through Javascript to a url on the same origin/domain without SSL/HTTPS?

I know it's a security risks on cross-origins, but on the same origin?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the origin. When you send data with http there are not encrypted or anything. So anyone connected to the same network than you can intercept them. So of course if you send your login and password anyone with a minimum computer and network knowledge can get them.

Comment: Thanks. When you said that I realised that I have also made that on my own during my education. haha :) Sniffing password.

Comment: Yeah but it can be dangerous with all sensible data you can send to your server or receive from it not only with passwords. I would prefer not to send my credit card number and key through an http connexion ;)